# Android ConstraintLayout Center Aligning Horizontally With Multiple Buttons

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I recently started playing around with ConstraintLayout in android studio (might use it in my app later) and I want to create a layout that has 5 buttons in one row and has 10 rows of 5 buttons. I got it right except that i want the buttons to all resize to the same width while filling the whole row (no gaps between buttons).

[A example of the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6gt1.png)

my current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="lotterynumbergenerator.johnferrazlopez.com.southafricanlotteryguide.other.SaveNumbers">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="01"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="02"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="03"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="04"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="05"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="06"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="07"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="08"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="09"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button9" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Another thing I see in the xml is this message in the  tags is "This view is not constrained vertically: at runtime it will jump to the left unless you add a vertical constraint"

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

[image: How i want it to space out on a bigger scrn]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a sample of what you are looking for using `10dp` as the margin. I created just a single row, but additional rows will follow the same pattern. This mock up uses a horizontal chain with a chain style of "spread". (`app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"`) The width of the buttons are set to "0dp" ("match constraints"). Start and end margins take care of getting the spacing right. The layout works for portrait and landscape and different screen sizes.

Adding a constraint that ties each button to the parent top takes care of the "not vertically constrained" error message. Views must be horizontally and vertically constrained.

**Portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**
[image]

And the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="01"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="02"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="03"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="04"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="05"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what i meant is that i wanted all the buttons evenly spread out. so no matter what size the display is the buttons will all shrink or grow. basically they must all have the same margin of 10dp. i edited my answer to show what i want. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you link all first buttons of each line into a vertical chain, you'll get rid of the error message and the heights of your lines will also automatically resize. Try `0dp` or a fixed value such as `40dp` or `@dimen/buttonHeight` to optimize the height of your buttons.

Building on your code and Cheticamp's code, here is what you could do:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="01"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="02"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="03"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="04"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="05"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="06"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="07"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="08"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="09"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="11"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="12"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button11"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="13"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button11"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="14"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button11"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="15"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button11"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"